# How do you use Tiled object layer?

Tags: java, dictionary, editor, tile

I'm not really sure if this is the place to be asking this but I was trying to use the program [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) but I'm not sure where to start. I have looked at its documentations but it's not that useful as I already have some experience in using a tiled editor in a game engine (GameMaker), but I'm working straight up Java for this project.

How does the Tiled object layer work? Does it allow me to place enemies in the tiled editor that would show up and actually move in the game or are they just static images like a tile?

Also if it does allow what I programed for the enemy how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiled allows you to edit layers of tiles and items.  There's tile layers which represent a 2D grid of images, and item layers which are just polygons with properties.

After you create a map, its up to you to do something with that data. Tiled is not like GameMaker. All Tiled does is allow you to read, write, and edit data.

I recommend you use [LIBGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) as a game engine, and Tiled to create your maps. LIBGDX has support for loading and rendering tiled maps.

To create enemies, you'd place some polygons, add attributes to these polygons, and create enemies based on these properties when parsing the Tiled map in your game.

Comment: Is there any tutorial that you can link me to that would show how to add attributes to the polygons? Also I don't want to use another engine for now I just want to use Java and its methods.

Comment: That's great, you'll learn a lot!  LIBGDX is a game engine, but its a lot more low level than GameMarker. If you won't look into it now, **please** remember it. It makes many things easier after you've mastered the basics. The format for Tiled is a little complex. [Here's a tutorial.](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/level-design/introduction-to-tiled-map-editor/)

Comment: While looking at it does go a little more in-depth of how to implement it but for the object layer do I have to work around that system. For example: make a variable name that is the same that I would put for that object layer and set its value in the editor?

Comment: You don't need to follow the tutorial exactly. Again, tiled just edits data. You decide what that data means in your code.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm starting to understand now thanks for the tips and tut as well as the engine!

Comment: Good luck! Libgdx has a steep learning curve. Just follow the tutorials and ask for help when you need it.